# asio::error_code::message() выводит не то, что должно

Tags: c++, visual-studio, asio

У меня есть код

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <asio\ts\buffer.hpp>
#include <asio\ts\internet.hpp>

int main() {
    asio::error_code ec;

    asio::io_context context;

    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1", ec), 80);

    asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(context);

    socket.connect(endpoint, ec);

    if (!ec) {
        std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Failed to connect to address:\n" << ec.message() <<std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

, который должен выводить `Failed to connect to address:` и описание ошибки, но выводит `Failed to connect to address: ╧юфъы■ўхэшх эх єёЄрэютыхэю, Є.ъ. ъюэхўэ√щ ъюья№■ЄхЁ юЄтхЁу чряЁюё эр яюфъы■ўхэшх.`
В чём может быть проблема?

Visual Studio 2019

Comment: `#include <asio\ts\buffer.hpp>` - и это работает?

Comment: пофиксите вывод символов юникода - без текста ошибки вряд ли что-то можно сказать

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch да, работает. В чём проблема?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch какой еще ошибки?

Comment: в том, что по стандарту в путях хидеров используются обычные слэши `/` - вот такие

Comment: всмысле какой? Той которая у вас крокозябрами выводится

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я не задавал вопрос "Почему выводится эта ошибка и я не могу подключиться к 127.0.0.1?".

Comment: ну так я же вам написал: пофиксите вывод символов юникода - более развернуто о том же самом вам написали ниже в ответе

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch хорошо, спасибо. Но тогда я не понимаю зачем вы написали "без текста ошибки вряд ли что-то можно сказать".

Comment: это уже к вопросу: "почему у вас возникает ошибка?"

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что Ваша консоль работает в кодировке 866, а строка выводится в cp1251. И там написано "Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение." А вот почему - это уже другой вопрос, скорее всего никто на локалхосте не хочет Вашего подключения (да, очень часто такая программа как скайп захватывает 80 и 443 порт)

Comment: спасибо, я думал, что message() возвращает строку на английском языке, а не на русском. Как я могу сделать так, чтобы мне возвращалась строка на английском языке?

Comment: переключить язык системы на английский

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/552164/is-it-possible-to-have-different-applications-set-to-different-locales